# Uncheck previously clicked gridview item on click of a new item

Tags: android, gridview, clicklistener

I am using a custom BaseAdapter to inflate a layout with a checkbox and textview in a gridview.

```
public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    if(view==null){
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_font_grid_details,null);
    }

    final TextView tvFontName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_font_detail_name);
    final CheckBox ivFontName = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkedImage);


    if(!isColor) {

        Log.d("fontNames"," "+fonts[i]);
        FontUtil.setDrawpTypeFace_(fonts[i],tvFontName);

        tvFontName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ivFontName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ivFontName.setChecked(true);
                listener.fontSet(fonts[i]);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

In the click listener for each item, on click, I make the checkbox go visible and checked (checkbox if defined invisible by default in XML declaration). What I need to do it when I click a different item, I need to uncheck the previously checked item. Is there a way to know which child view was clicked previously?

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1** Store the clicked item id/position in a list/array.

**Step 2** when any item clicked, just loop on list and mark them uncheck.

**Step 3** Call NotifydatasetChanged or notifyItemRangeChanged something.